# HTML parse in Java?

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I'm trying to parse (with jsoup) some specific text from a website, but it doesn't work for me.
[LINK TO SITE](https://www.virustotal.com/sv/url/cbf2d00f974d212b6700e7051f8b23f2038e876173066af41780e09481ef1cdd/analysis/)

It's the number "43" in red text that I am interested in at the top-right of the page.

This is what I tried:

```
String test;

public void scan(String url) throws Exception {

    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();        
    Elements votes = document.select("#malicious-votes .pull-right");
    test = votes.text();
}

public int returnVotes(){
    return test();
}
```

~ ~ ~

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Scan_VirusTotal virustotal = new Scan_VirusTotal();     
    virustotal.scan("https://www.virustotal.com/sv/url/cbf2d00f974d212b6700e7051f8b23f2038e876173066af41780e09481ef1cdd/analysis/1407146081");      
    System.out.println(virustotal.returnVotes());
```

This prints nothing. Other elements work fine with this exact method, so I'm really confused as to why this particular piece of text won't parse.

Ideas? Thanks.

EDIT - added some HTML from page as requested:

```
<div style="display:block" class="pull-right value text-red" id="malicious-votes">44</div>
```

Comment: Please provide some sample HTML instead of posting a link to the website in question.

Comment: Just linking to the page shows nothing of what source you are actually looking at, thus you should always include the code instead of only linking.

Comment: Well I explained which part I was referring to. If you click inspect code it will take you straight to the relative code. The reason why I didn't include is because the tree is quite big and so I didn't want to cut anything out :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using this instead:

```
Elements votes = document.select("#malicious-votes");
test = votes.text();
```

I tried this `$("#malicious-votes .pull-right")` in the browser console of the given page, gives me empty array. But $("#malicious-votes") gives me the vote div which itself has the class `pull-right`.

Answer (score 2):

Your selector should be:

`"#malicious-votes"`, not `"#malicious-votes .pull-right"`.

`"#malicious-votes .pull-right"` selects any elements with class `pull-right` that are descendants of `#malicious-votes`. What you want is the `#malicious-votes` element itself.